# Qtip2, hide small tip on tooltip modal?

Tags: php, jquery, qtip2

I've looked everywhere on the qtip site, was not able to find an answer to this.  I'm using Qtip2, with the Modal plugin.  Anyone know how I can hide the small little "tip" thing from my tool tip?

Here's my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!-- TOOL TIP MODAL TO ADD CALENDAR EVENT->
$('.add_event_tooltip').live('mouseover', function(event) {
    var thedate =  $(this).attr("thedate"); 
    date = new Date(thedate), //convert date
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],
    converted = days[date.getDay()] + ", " + months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();
    $(this).qtip({
        id: 'modal',
        content: {
            ajax: {url: 'includes/cal_add_event.php',type: 'GET',data: { rel: thedate}},
            title: { text: 'Creating Event: ' + converted,button: true}
        },
        position: {my: 'top left',at: 'top left',target: $('#leftside')},
        show: {event: 'click',solo: true,modal: true},
        hide: false,
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
      }); 
}); 
</script>
```

If you can, focuse on the Position setting, I've placed it on my page where I want it to be, just want to get rid of the small "pointer" "tip" thing..

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Found your question after searching for a solution myself. @xzyfer's suggestions didn't work for me, but it was a hint in the right direction.

What worked was setting `tip: false`.

```
$(this).qtip({
    ...
    style: {
        ...
        tip: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).qtip({
    ...
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded',
        tip: null
});
```

Otherwise try:

```
$(this).qtip({
    ...
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded',
        tip: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }
});
```